# Working on my doubly linked list, can't figure out how to define the set method

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

```
public void set(int index, T item) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.size()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        Node<T> tmp1 = front;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            tmp1 = tmp1.next;
        }
        Node<T> tmp2 = new Node<T>(tmp1.prev, item, tmp1.next);
        tmp1.prev.next = tmp2;
        tmp1.next.prev = tmp2;
}
```

Can somebody please help me figure out how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudo code that should work.

```
set(index, item)
{
    Node<T> tmp1 = front;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        tmp1 = tmp1.next;
    }

    Node beforeNewNode = tmp1.prev//  tmp1 is in the index we want to replace so we need the node before tmp1. That node is tmp1.prev
    Node afterNewNode = tmp1.next//tmp1.next will be the node after the new node
    Node newNode = new Node(beforeNewNode, item, afterNewNode);
    beforeNewNode.next = newNode//connect the new node to the node that should be in front of it
    afterNewNode.prev = newNode//connect the new node to the node that should come after it.

}
```

Comment: Hi! shouldn't the afterNewNode be tmp1.next because we want to replace tmp1?

Comment: Draw 6 squares. Now try to insert a square into one of the indexes. You will see that the square that's currently in the index now comes after the newly inserted square and the square that was in front of the square in the index come before the newly inserted square.

Comment: ohh yeah. I think i didnt make it clear. I want to replace the value not inset a new node. and I used the code. still doesnt work. thanks regardless

Comment: Oh, yea then you are right. I thought you were trying to insert. I updated the sudo code.